# How does a service discovers service registry in microservice architecture with client side service discovery?

Tags: microservices, service-discovery, system-design

Service Registry is used for discovering services in micro-service architecture.

As service registry is itself a service then how does it gets discovered by other services ?

Comment: Typically the details of how to contact the service registry (or how to discover the service registry) are statically provided to those who want to interact with the service registry.  For example, `/etc/resolv.conf` can (on Unixy systems) be used to inform processes how to use DNS to resolve hosts/services.

Comment: A pretty good article about this topic: https://iximiuz.com/en/posts/service-discovery-in-kubernetes/